# Invisible part of BitmapImage

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, bitmapimage, rect

I have a SkinnableContainer, which contains s:BitmapImage. I need a part of the image (Rect) to be fully transparent. Just make a transparent cut-out, that would be easy to position.
The image in the background is width="300" height="200" and transparent area should be width="200" height="20" and right="0" bottom="50". I managed to achieve similar effect with BlendMode.OVERLAY, but I believe there must be a better way.

Any ideas, suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0):

You could apply another object (like a UIMovieClip) to the image as a Mask. You could also manipulate the pixels of a Bitmap and set it as the source of the BitmapImage. This may or may not make sense depending on your specific requirements.

Comment: I need this for image with scale9Grid.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
               creationComplete="onComplete(event)"
               backgroundColor="0xEEEEEE">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.graphics.ImageSnapshot;
            import mx.skins.RectangularBorder;      

            protected function onComplete(event:Event):void
            {
                var bW:int = 300;
                var bH:int = 200;

                var X:int = 0;
                var Y:int = 150;
                var W:int = 200;
                var H:int = 20;

                var topRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,bW,Y);

                var righRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(W,0,bW-W,bH);

                var bottomRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,Y+H,bW,bH-(Y+H));

                var targetBitmapData:BitmapData = ImageSnapshot.captureBitmapData(original);

                var newBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(bW,bH,true,0x00000000);

                newBitmapData.copyPixels(targetBitmapData, topRect, new Point(0, 0),null, null, true);

                newBitmapData.copyPixels(targetBitmapData, righRect, new Point(W, 0),null, null, true);

                newBitmapData.copyPixels(targetBitmapData, bottomRect, new Point(0,Y+H),null, null, true);

                modified.source = new Bitmap(newBitmapData);
            }                   
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:VGroup gap="10" left="10" top="10">
        <s:Group id="original">
            <s:Rect width="300" height="200">
                <s:fill>
                    <s:SolidColor/>
                </s:fill>
                <s:stroke>
                    <s:SolidColorStroke color="0xFF0000"/>
                </s:stroke>
            </s:Rect>
        </s:Group>
        <s:Group>
            <mx:Image width="300" height="200" id="modified" />
            <s:Rect top="0" left="0" right="0" bottom="0">
                <s:stroke>
                    <s:SolidColorStroke color="0xFF0000"/>
                </s:stroke>
            </s:Rect>
        </s:Group>          
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Application>
```

An example for your particular case, maybe you'll extend this.